# Using pyfmi with multiprocessing for simulation of Modelica FMUs

Tags: python-2.7, modelica, fmi

I am trying to simulate multiple Modelica FMUs in parallel using python/pyfmi and multiprocessing. However I am not able to return any pyfmi FMI objects from the subprocesses once the FMUs are initialized. It seems that pyfmi FMI objects (e.g. pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS2 or pyfmi.fmi.FMUState2) are not pickable. I also tried dill to pickle, which doesn't work for me eather. With dill the objects are picklable though, meaning no error, but somehow corrupted if I try to reload them afterwards. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I already managed to simulate parallel FMUs using the Pool function. But what I want to do is the following:
1. Open Pool of processes and map with FMUs
2. Initialize and simulate multiple FMUs in parallel for only one timestep
3. Return results to be further processed
4. Close processes
5. Open new Pool and re-initialize with the previous FMU states and input values (which are not pickable as I understand)
6. Simulate next timestep
Maybe that wasn't too clear in my above question

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that pyfmi.fmiFMUModelCS2 is a Cython class dependent on external libraries which makes it unpickable. So it is not possible unfortunately.

If you want to use multiprocessing the only way forward that I see is that you first create the processes and then load the FMUs into the separate processes. In this way you do not need to pickle the classes.

Comment: Actually I already managed to simulate parallel FMUs using the Pool function. But what I want to do is the following:
1. Open Pool of processes and map with FMUs
2. Initialize and simulate multiple FMUs in parallel for only one timestep
3. Return results to be further processed
4. Close processes
5. Open new Pool and re-initialize with the previous FMU states (which are not pickable as I understand)

Comment: Ok I see. The FMU states are not pickable as it is basically just a pointer to an internal data structure in the FMU (different depending on the tool that exported the FMU). Your best bet would be to have a look at the FMI methods "fmi2SerializeFMUState" etc. With these you would have the option to store the FMU state to file and read it back. Unfortunately they are not currently supported in PyFMI but I don't believe it would be that much of an effort to include.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look into it and report back.

Comment: Hi Christian, after some weeks I looked into the described problem again, tried several workarounds, however without success. The solution that you proposed seems to be the last hope for me and I also looked into the fmi.pyx that can be found on github. The problem is that I am not very familiar with C coding and Cython though, actually completely unfamiliar. Could you give me some advise on how to implement these functions? Is there I way I can contribute to pyfmi?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem when I created EstimationPy. I ended up creating a wrapper for running parallel simulation of the same FMU using multiple processes.

I suggest you to look at the implementation here
https://github.com/lbl-srg/EstimationPy/blob/master/estimationpy/fmu_utils/fmu_pool.py

And to the example http://lbl-srg.github.io/EstimationPy/modules/examples/first_order.html#run-multiple-simulations

Comment: @ Marco Bonvini The code snippets in the example documentation are rather cryptic to me. Maybe there some confusion there? I do not understand the solitary `else` clause and `m` does not seem to be initialised anywhere. Otherwise, thanks a lot for pointing to your great module!

Comment: The docs are selecting which lines to include in the snippet. The lines must have changed with a recent commit and the result are misleading code snippets. Anyway, it's better to directly look at the source code of the example https://github.com/lbl-srg/EstimationPy/blob/master/estimationpy/examples/first_order/run_pool.py

Answer (score 0):

The [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) module allows multiprocessing with a similar interface as the `multiprocessing` but relies on [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) instead of `pickle` for serialisation.
The `Pool` method works for parallel execution of `model.simulate`, provided that results are handled in memory:

```
n_core = 2
n_simulation = 10
# ====

import pyfmi
model = pyfmi.load_fmu(path_fmu)

def worker(*args):
    model.reset()
    print "================> %d" % args[0]
    return model.simulate(options=dict(result_handling="memory"))["y"]


from pathos.multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(n_core)
out = pool.map(worker, range(n_simulation))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Note in the above snippet that it is necessary to handle results in memory : `options=dict(result_handling="memory")`.
The default is to use *temporary files* which works for when the amount of simulations is small.
However, the longer the queue, the higher the chance to get something like

```
Exception in thread Thread-27:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 389, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 260, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 250, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/home/USER/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

which I fail to grasp.